# How can I add lightbox to paperclip multiple uploads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, lightbox

I've got a table of venues, where each record has many images uploaded using paperclip into another table of venuephotos. Currently all the photos are displayed on the venues show page using:

```
 <div class="venue_photos_container">
   <% for venuephoto in @venue.venuephotos %>
     <%= link_to image_tag(venuephoto.venuephoto.url(:thumb), :class => "venue_photo"), venuephoto.venuephoto.url(:original) %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

The page source shows these photos as:

```
<div class="venue_photos_container">
    <a href="/system/venuephotos/1/original/image2.png?1300712562"><img alt="image2" class="venue_photo" src="/system/venuephotos/1/thumb/image2.png?1300712562" /></a>
    <a href="/system/venuephotos/4/original/image3.png?1300714288"><img alt="image3" class="venue_photo" src="/system/venuephotos/4/thumb/image3.png?1300714288" /></a>
    <a href="/system/venuephotos/5/original/image4.png?1300714548"><img alt="image4" class="venue_photo" src="/system/venuephotos/5/thumb/image4.png?1300714548" /></a>
</div>
```

How can I go about adding lightbox to my app to display these images? The Lightbox2 guide mentions adding rel="lightbox[imagesetname]" to each link tag. I would like to have all the uploaded photos display in a single imageset on the show page.

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Comment: actually i answered below with a comment for clarification but figured i would post one more comment here :-X.  so are you trying to just have one image shown on the page that when clicked on will allow the user to do like a little lightbox slideshow through all the other images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to image_tag(venuephoto.venuephoto.url(:thumb), :class => "venue_photo", ), venuephoto.venuephoto.url(:original), :rel => "lightbox[imagesetname]" %>
```

Comment: actually now that i think about it i should have asked for a little clarification.  are you trying to show thumbnails on the page and then have lightbox display the full size image when the thumbnail gets clicked?  let me know and i can edit my answer to fit your needs

Comment: thanks for the answer thats great!, yea I would like to have just one image displayed on the show page and when clicked it allows the user to flick through all the photos.